# Post json encode parameter swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, swift, swift2

Can you suggest me how to pass following parameter in swift or objective c

```
         let parameters = ["Access_Key":"0699DADD8A2B5FC2E8FF6FF5DDFE03EEDB3ED2132B29EA4F28","Packages":["Length":self.Length,"Type":"","Kg":self.Weight,"Height":self.Height,"Width":self.Width,"Name":self.SkuName],
                      "issignaturerequired":"true",
                      "Outputs":["LABEL_PNG_100X175"],
                      "DeliveryReference":"86882",
                      "Destination":["ContactPerson":self.CustomerFirstname,"Address":["PostCode":self.PostalCode,"StreetAddress":self.Address1,"Suburb":self.City,"BuildingName":"","City":self.City,"CountryCode":"AU"],"PhoneNumber":"","Email":self.CustomerEmail,"Name":self.CustomerFirstname],
                      "PrintToPrinter":"true",
                      "SendTrackingEmail":"",
        "Commodities":["UnitKg":"1.0000","Currency":"NZD","Country":"NZ","Units":"1","Description":"Drums Drum Accessories Drum Bags","UnitValue":"44.0"],
        "DeliveryInstructions":"None"
                     ]
    Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://api.omniparcel.com/labels/printcheapestcourier",parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response)
    }
}
```

I am new to iOS

Comment: use "AFNetworking" for objective-C or "Alamofire" for swift. You can find both libraries on github

Comment: i know that but can u suggest me how to post son encode parameter

Comment: see $attachment parameter

Comment: If you set the request serializer to JSON and put it in to a dictionary and pass as a parameter, and the sub JSON put that in separate dictionary and set it to the "Packages" key. I didn't try that but should work :)

Comment: something like NSMutableDictionary *subJSon  = ------                NSMutableDictionary *paramerters = @{@"Packages":subJson}

Comment: Read the Alamofire library's documentation

Comment: okk but how to pass header

Comment: @ Irshad, you must read the Alamofire library's documentation properly.

Comment: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Alamofire/3.2.1/Classes/Manager.html

Read this documentation try it if you don't success come back with your code.

Comment: i got "JSON could not be serialized. Input data was nil or zero length" error

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use [EVReflection](https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection) for your JSON objects in Swift.

Just create an object for your JSON Object and then pass it to Alamofire with **myJsonObject.toDictionary()** as parameters.

Comment: i want to post this type

Comment: I think you miss this in the request method: `parameters: parameters as? [String : AnyObject]`

also this is your response JSON: `response.result.value`, try printing that

Comment: i got "JSON could not be serialized. Input data was nil or zero length" error

Comment: that applies to the response you get from the server, not to what you are sending. Check the url maybe?